# Looking for TRMM data of 4km resolution or more of july 2014

Tags: data-request

I have been looking for this data without much luck. I want TRMM/PR/GPM daily or hourly precipitation data (mm/hr) with a spatial resolution of 4km or more.

Comment: Could you give us a brief list of where you've already looked? I'm guessing you've seen the 5km data at https://pmm.nasa.gov/data-access/downloads/trmm (under Level 1), but it doesn't quite meet your needs?

Comment: I looked through 2A25 product of TRMM/PR and other level 3 and level 1 products. But level three products have coarse resolution and level 1 products don't give rainfall data directly instead they give brightness temperatures,etc. Looking for preprocessing information of 2A25 currently.